# SQL Query to LINQ Lambda expression

Tags: sql, linq, lambda

I am trying to convert a bit of SQL containing a LEFT OUTER JOIN with a GROUP BY clause into a LINQ Lambda expression.

The SQL I need to convert is:-

```
SELECT m.MemberExternalPK
FROM Member.Member AS m LEFT OUTER JOIN Member.Account AS a ON m.MemberID = a.MemberID
GROUP BY MemberExternalPK
HAVING COUNT(AccountID) = 0
```

I have managed to get it working correctly with an INNER JOIN between Member and Accounts like this (for a count of Account = 1) but this does not work for Accounts with a count of 0 (hence the LEFT OUTER JOIN is required):-

```
Members.Join(Accounts, m => m.MemberID, a => a.MemberID, (m, a) => new {m, a})
.GroupBy(t => t.m.MemberExternalPK, t => t.a)
.Where(grp => grp.Count(p => p.AccountID != null) == 1)
.Select(grp => grp.Key)
```

I have been trying to experiment with the .DefaultIfEmpty() keyword but have so far been unsuccessful. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

**Query syntax**

```
var members = new List<Member>
{
    new Member {MemberId = 1, MemberExternalPk = 100},
    new Member {MemberId = 2, MemberExternalPk = 200}
};

var accounts = new List<Account>
{
    new Account {AccountId = 1, MemberId = 1}
};

var query =
    from m in members
    join a in accounts on m.MemberId equals a.MemberId into ma
    from ma2 in ma.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where ma2 == null
    group ma2 by m.MemberExternalPk into grouped
    select  new {grouped.Key};
```

The result of this example is that only the number 200 is returned. As it will only return the MemberExternalPk for members that don't have an account. i.e. As MemberId 2 doesn't have a related Account object, it is not included in the reuslts.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = members.GroupJoin(accounts,m=>m.MemberId, a => a.MemberId,
                (m,a) => new {m,a})
                .Where(x=>x.a.Count()==0)
                .Select(s=>s.m.MemberExternalPk);
```